# I frequent the pub often enough

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct to use?

> I **frequent** the pub **often enough**

or

> I **frequent** the pub **enough**?

I looked up in the dictionary and found that **"frequent"** itself means **"to visit a place often"**. That's why I am confused. Should I use the word **"often"** here or it would be too much?

Thank you!

Comment: "Often enough" for *what?* Often enough to justify saying you *frequent* the pub? You should note that this use of *frequent* as a verb [has massively declined](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+frequents&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20frequents%3B%2Cc0), and only really occurs today in literary or facetious contexts.

Comment: both are valid to me, in different contexts. what do you want to say?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic phrase is

> *to do something* often enough

which means to do *something* quite often.

You can think of the phrase as

> I frequent the pub **often enough** *(for it to be considered a habit)*.

Comment: It can also be used as a somewhat non-committal response, when a person doesn't want to admit to being somewhere (say, the pub) on an all too regular basis. :)